# How to create a model for predicting the number of visitors

Tags: ai-design

I want to create a model to predict the number of visitors.

Currently, I have a year's csv data for predicting the number of visitors, which is collected every 10 seconds.

I would like to predict the number of future visitors on a daily basis based on this data for the past year.

What kind of method or model can I use to achieve this? I can use a graphics board for learning.

If you have any page of sample codes, it would be very helpful.

[image: sample chart of one day]

Comment: Do you have any other data attributes, or just the time-of-day?

Comment: At the moment it is only time vs. count.
I may add weather and other information in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Straight answer:

There is no right answer as it depends on many factors. But here are some keywords you can look into:

Keywords about your problem:

- **Time Series**
- Periodic
- **Forecasting**.
- Uni-variable

About the model, I'd recommend checking ARIMA. But before jumping into code.

A good problem solving with Data Science is a dynamic process for deeply understanding your **business** while *testing hypothesis with* **data**.

##### Business:

- If you are predicting visitors in a beach, for instance, it will probably depend on weather, weekdays and holidays.
- If it's a bank, you might have more visits on pay-day and people may choose the time with less expected line length.
- If it's an emergency hospital, you'll find a whole new situation.

So I encourage you to think of your real problem before (or while) diving into math and programming.

##### Data:

Depending on your available data, you could test some hypothesis. For example: "The weekday won't interfere much on the visitors". Once you are familiar with your data and your business, than you can even model it into a simple periodic regression. For example:

- Everyday my restaurant has 2 main peaks, one for lunch and other for dinner.
- I'll assume my data is well described by 2 Gaussian distribution across the day.
- Model it by a simple regression to find the best parameters for your Gaussian curves and than check how well it fits.
- Check the cases where the model fails and set new hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that as a reference! It was very informative with concrete examples!
I felt that factors such as the weather and temperature are also important, since in my case I have to take measurements in places where I am exposed to direct sunlight.

Answer (score 0):

There are various cheat sheets to recommend what predictive model to use in different situations. Here’s a couple to guide you on options for your dataset.

[image: Scimitar Learn Cheat Sheet] https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html

For this first cheat sheet with your example, you would begin with the start icon. For the first question > 50 samples, the answer is yes. For the second question predict category, the answer is no. For the third question predict quantity, the answer is yes. For the fourth question, < 100K samples, the answer is yes . The suggested type of regression analysis to try from this cheat sheet is a SGD Regressor.

[image: Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Cheat Sheet] https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/algorithm-cheat-sheet

For the cheat sheet you example begin with the question what do you want to do. The answer is predict values; so again we see this should be some type of regression analysis. There are a few options on this one that would be appropriate to try, such as a Poisson Regression.

After deciding which model to use the next decision is how to implement the model. Kimball made a statement a good decade ago,  *In today’s environment, most organizations should use a vendor-supplied ETL tool as a general rule.* This was mainly due to maintenance costs. We’ve reached the same level of maturity with data science tools that same logic can be applied for common data science models.

Comment: Hi, @Christopher! Those are nice guidelines. But maybe you could try to be more specific. At least guiding the user through this mindmap and helping them finding their case.